# How to get a property value using Reflection if the property name is defined as "name"

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have the following code to compare two collections to one another...

```
    //code invocation
    CollectionComparer comp = new CollectionComparer("name", "ASC");
    this.InnerList.Sort(comp);
```

class

```
public class CollectionComparer : IComparer
{
    private String _property;
    private String _order;

    public CollectionComparer(String Property, String Order)
    {
        this._property = Property;
        this._order = Order;
    }

    public int Compare(object obj1, object obj2)
    {
        int returnValue;

        Type type = obj1.GetType();
        PropertyInfo propertie1 = type.GetProperty(_property); // returns null here
        Type type2 = obj2.GetType();
        PropertyInfo propertie2 = type2.GetProperty(_property); // returns null here

        object finalObj1 = propertie1.GetValue(obj1, null); // Null Reference Exception thrown here, because propertie1 is null
        object finalObj2 = propertie2.GetValue(obj2, null);

        IComparable Ic1 = finalObj1 as IComparable;
        IComparable Ic2 = finalObj2 as IComparable;

        if (_order == "ASC")
        {
            returnValue = Ic1.CompareTo(Ic2);
        }
        else
        {
            returnValue = Ic2.CompareTo(Ic1);
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

The code seems to work fine, except when I try to sort a property called "name". When comparing that property both the variables `propertie1` and `propertie2` are null, and the code throws an exception because of that.

So my question is how to use reflection to get the value of a property with the name of "name"?

Comment: What is an exception Message ?

Comment: The exception is a null reference message... I'll update my code accordingly...

Comment: Show the POCO definition of the type you are comparing, nothing wrong with the reflection code?

Comment: Where is `name`? Show how its defined. Or simply use proper [`GetProperty` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) yourself, because you are either messing with `BindingFlags` or maybe even trying to get `field` value?

Comment: How does the actual class looks like `obj1` is an instance from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out... I guess uppercase counts when doing reflection...

I needed to change the code invocation to...

```
//code invocation
CollectionComparer comp = new CollectionComparer("Name", "ASC");
this.InnerList.Sort(comp);
```

As the property was actually called "Name" and not "name"

Answer (score 0):

By the way, is **_property** variable set?

How about this extension method:

```
public static object GetProperty(this object instance, string name)
    {
        if (instance == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");

        if (name == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");

        Type type = instance.GetType();
        PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (property == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Type {0} does not have a property {1}", type, name));

        object result = property.GetValue(instance, null);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I've already tried changing the bindingflags to this `type.GetProperty(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);` and I still get a null reference

Comment: And what objects are you passing in to the Compare method? Do they have the "name" property